# How should I deal with the error message of “fatal error U1077, return code ‘0x2’ as I compiled libf2c?

Tags: visual-c++

Language & Platform version: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express
Operating system : Windows 10
Relevant software: Ipopt-3.9.3

I’m trying to compile libf2c related to Ipopt-3.9.3, I open a Visual Studio DOS prompt and go into the directory and type the command as follows:

cd C:\Ipopt-3.9.3\Ipopt\MSVisualStudio\v8\libf2c
nmake -f makefile.vc all

Then, there displayed the following error messages.

```
Arithchk.c
Arithchk.c(240): error C2065:'ssize_t": undeclared identifier
Arithchk.c(242): error C2065:'ssize_t":underclared identifier
NMAKE: fatal error U1077: ' "C:\Program File(x86)\Mircrosoft Visual 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"';
return code '0x2' Stop
```

The following is the .h files  included in arithchk.c

```
#include<string.h>/*possibly for ssize_t */
#include<sys/types.h>/* another possible place for ssize_t */
```

row 239 to 242 of the codes are as follows

```
#else /*}{*/
if (sizeof(size_t)!=sizeof(ssize_t))
fprintf(f,"/*sizeof(size_t)=%d but sizeof(ssize_t)=%d */\n",
(int)sizeof(size_t),(int)sizeof(ssize_t));
```

Since I'm just an initiate, I don't know how to correct row 240 and 242, and expect for your aid.

Thank you very much for your attention, and I’m looking forward to your kind help!

Comment: I've checked the .h files, they don't include the variable of ssize_t, it seems that the solution is hidden in the software package of libf2c.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded another version of arithchk.c related to libf2c from this site http://josephsmith.numis.northwestern.edu/cgi-bin/sempercvs.cgi/f2c/libf2c/arithchk.c?revision=1.2&view=markup, and then everything goes well.

Comment: I downloaded the whole tarball of libf2c from the above mentioned site, and it can be compiled smoothly.

Comment: Hi 'Mi Peichao', I downloaded the sources from where you said and nmake ran without errors, but it only generated '.o' files. How can I generate the library?